# How to stop swipping in flutter (after one swipe animation)

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-layout, gesturedetector

I am using a list to store my items and changing the items indexes if swiped left or right but now when I am trying to swipe it does not stop I want the swipe to go from 1->2 or 2->3 or 3->2 but instead it goes 1->4 or 4->1.
This code below is the part of my program where I am swiping and calling the functions (where I increased the sensitivity to 15).

```
 return GestureDetector(
        onHorizontalDragUpdate: (dis) {
          if (dis.delta.dx > 15) {
            prevPage();
          }
          else if (dis.delta.dx < -15) { //User swiped from right to left
            nextPage();
          }
        },
```

And these are the functions which it is calling.

```
  void nextPage() {
    if(currPage !=4) {
      setState(() {
        currPage += 1;
      });
    }
  }

  void prevPage() {
    if(currPage != 1) {
      setState(() {
        currPage -= 1;
      });
    }
  }
```

How can I fix this situation?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html